# How can I compare paths,definitions,parameters and responses between two OpenAPI / Swagger json API documentation?

Tags: api, swagger, documentation, openapi, openapi-generator

I would like to find if there is a solution that helps with finding the differences between two different API versions of the same product(Swagger/Open API 2.0). For example, this tool : https://github.com/Sayi/swagger-diff compares parameters, responses, notes, http method(GET,POST,PUT,DELETE...), but doesn't compare definitions, which is the main thing I need currently.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-diff instead. It includes definitions, but the output is less refined, if I remember correctly.