# How can I compare 2 Swagger versions and add any change notes on the differences found?

Tags: json, documentation, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I want to compare 2 swagger API versions(previous and current ones) in order to find the differences between them. Also, for all the changes identified, I want to make change notes and send them along with the swagger to a team. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Actions - Compare and find differences between two OAS V3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460901/github-actions-compare-and-find-differences-between-two-oas-v3-files), [How can I compare paths,definitions,parameters and responses between two OpenAPI / Swagger json API documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52152321/113116), [How to compare two OpenAPI 3.x YAML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67740824/113116)

Comment: Here is a list of tools you can use https://github.com/tinohager/swagger-diff